# Play Framework error and changes are useless

Tags: playframework

i just playing java with Play Framework tonight, it is easy and then i get this error: http://twitpic.com/7665ys. i have changed the script and refreshing the website but there's no changes.

Answer (score 1):

The error is very well described in the image you have posted: 'Sintax Error, insert ";"'

Don't you agree? :)

Comment: of course, but i make changes and still get problem altought i restart the service. Then i try change the Application.java with vim and hola the app was run beautifully